# Вебсокеты в django

Tags: django, websocket

Вообще без channels  можно ли работать с вебсокетами в django  ? Можно ли связать socket io +node с django ?

Comment: Не знаком с `Socket.IO`, но скажу, что Вы можете использовать сразу 2 сервера. Принимайте запросы асинхронным и через него обращайтесь к `Django`. Асинхронный сервер при этом может быть любой.